# Nvidia driver update from 525 display ports no longer working with GTX 2070

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, display, dependencies

**Problem:**
After attempting to update my nvidia driver, I  got stuck in a constant black screen on reboot. I was able to get back to my desktop but now my display port connections / dual monitors do not work. Only my HDMI on single monitor is working.

**Background:**
This has happened within the span of a day. I was trying to get the latest Tekken to work and I figured I would update my nvidia driver from 525. I initially chose 550 but I missed that this was the beta version.  Initially trying to install 550, I was having problems so I ran the below commands:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-550 --fix-missing
```

and then

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-550 --fix-broken install
```

I don't recall what fully happened from this output and then I ran this command:

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

From those 3 commands, I removed some Nvidia dependencies that I needed (I think) and I was living in the terminal for a while where I couldn't even return to my desktop. Going through my logs I did see this error but I don't know if it was the main error or not.

```
RmInitAdapter
rm_init_adapter failed
nvidia-drm Failed to allocate NvKMsKapiDevice
```

From other posts on here and nvidia's form, eventually I purged all Nvidia driver, disconnected my gpu, and was able to get to my desktop from my mobo via HDMI.  Using Software & Updates > Additional Drivers, I reinstalled multiple versions because I have been trying to fix my issue but I've been running out of ideas. I have these 3 versions installed: nvidia driver metapackage nvidia-525,535, and now I am currently on 545.

**Logs / Config Info:**
OS: Ubuntu 22.04 with GNOME
Kernel: 6.5.0-15-generic (and tried on 6.5.0-14-generic)

nvidia-smi

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 545.29.06              Driver Version: 545.29.06    CUDA Version: 12.3     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070        Off | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   38C    P8               3W / 175W |    496MiB /  8192MiB |      3%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1490      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          143MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1755      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         70MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3049      G   ...irefox/3728/usr/lib/firefox/firefox      187MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4054      G   ...39692028,3432445436170888676,131072       52MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5373      G   ...,WinRetrieveSuggestionsOnlyOnDemand       36MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia
```

```
rc  glx-alternative-nvidia                            1.2.1~deb11u1                                    amd64        allows the selection of NVIDIA as GLX provider
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-545:amd64                          545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-545                              545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
rc  libnvidia-compute-450-server:amd64                450.248.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-470-server:amd64                470.223.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-510:amd64                       510.73.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                       amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-525:amd64                       525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-535:amd64                       535.154.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-545:amd64                       545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-545:i386                        545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-545:amd64                        545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-545:i386                         545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-egl-wayland1:amd64                      1:1.1.9-1.1                                      amd64        Wayland EGL External Platform library -- shared library
ii  libnvidia-eglcore:i386                            515.48.07-1                                      i386         NVIDIA binary EGL core libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-545:amd64                        545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-545:i386                         545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-545:amd64                         545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-545:amd64                          545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-545:i386                           545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-545:amd64                            545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-545:i386                             545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-525-open-6.5.0-15-generic    6.5.0-15.15~22.04.1+1                            amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-15 (objects)
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-525-open-6.5.0-15-lowlatency 6.5.0-15.15.1.1~22.04.1+1                        amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-15 (objects)
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-450-server                   450.248.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-470-server                   470.223.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-525                          525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-535                          535.154.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-545                          545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-dkms-450-server                            450.248.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
rc  nvidia-dkms-470-server                            470.223.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
rc  nvidia-dkms-525                                   525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
rc  nvidia-dkms-525-open                              525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package (open kernel module)
rc  nvidia-dkms-535                                   535.154.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
rc  nvidia-dkms-535-open                              535.154.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package (open kernel module)
ii  nvidia-dkms-545                                   545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-545                                 545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-firmware-545-545.29.06                     545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       amd64        Firmware files used by the kernel module
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-450-server                   450.248.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-470-server                   470.223.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-525                          525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-535                          535.154.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-545                          545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-545                          545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                                      0.8.17.1                                         all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                                   510.47.03-0ubuntu1                               amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-545                                  545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                           0.18.2                                           all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-545                     545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

Nvidia settings does show my one monitor via HDMI but not my others via display port. I have no idea what to do at this point so that my display ports work and I to get dual monitor working again.

Thanks for any assistance.

**Edit 1**
I changed to kernel 5.15 since I didn't realize 6.5 needed gcc-12. Then I repurged my nvidia drivers again, and reinstalled nvidia-driver-525 with gcc-11 and no luck still. I tried to go back to 6.5 with gcc-12 and attempted to go with 545 as well with no luck. I made things worse though because nvidia-smi no longer works with this error when running on 5.15 and I can no longer get to my desktop in 6.5.

```
Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch
```

Here is the updated grep search

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia
```

```
rc  glx-alternative-nvidia                            1.2.1~deb11u1                                    amd64        allows the selection of NVIDIA as GLX provider
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-525:amd64                          525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-525                              525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
rc  libnvidia-compute-450-server:amd64                450.248.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-470-server:amd64                470.223.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-510:amd64                       510.73.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                       amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-525:amd64                       525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-525:i386                        525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-535:amd64                       535.154.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-545:amd64                       545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-525:amd64                        525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-525:i386                         525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-egl-wayland1:amd64                      1:1.1.9-1.1                                      amd64        Wayland EGL External Platform library -- shared library
ii  libnvidia-eglcore:i386                            515.48.07-1                                      i386         NVIDIA binary EGL core libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-525:amd64                        525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-525:i386                         525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-525:amd64                         525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-525:amd64                          525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-525:i386                           525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-525:amd64                            525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-525:i386                             525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-525-open-6.5.0-15-generic    6.5.0-15.15~22.04.1+1                            amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-15 (objects)
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-525-open-6.5.0-15-lowlatency 6.5.0-15.15.1.1~22.04.1+1                        amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 6.5.0-15 (objects)
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-450-server                   450.248.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-470-server                   470.223.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-525                          525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-535                          535.154.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-545                          545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-dkms-450-server                            450.248.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
rc  nvidia-dkms-470-server                            470.223.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-dkms-525                                   525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
rc  nvidia-dkms-525-open                              525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package (open kernel module)
rc  nvidia-dkms-535                                   535.154.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
rc  nvidia-dkms-535-open                              535.154.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package (open kernel module)
rc  nvidia-dkms-545                                   545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-525                                 525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
rc  nvidia-fabricmanager-535                          535.154.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        Fabric Manager for NVSwitch based systems.
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-450-server                   450.248.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-470-server                   470.223.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-525                          525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-535                          535.154.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-545                          545.29.06-0ubuntu0.22.04.2                       amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-525                          525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                                      0.8.17.1                                         all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                                   510.47.03-0ubuntu1                               amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-525                                  525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                           0.18.2                                           all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-525                     525.147.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                      amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

I have no idea what I should do at this point to either get 6.5 or 5.15 working.

Comment: By chance, do you have nvidia-settings and can you open it via gnome (Not the terminal). If so, how does it show?

Comment: I can open nvidia settings and my monitor shows under X screen 0 and then my nvidia gpu is under GPU 0. My display ports do not show under here.  Was there a specific tab you wanted me to go look at? 

Running nvidia-settings via terminal to launch the gui does return this error in the console

```GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 17:41:56.184: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

Comment: You might try apt purge the nvidia packages in your listing with lines starting with "rc" -- They've been removed, but might have leftover config files that cannot be helping things. Did you apt install gcc-12 to get the nvidia modules to compile for the 6.5 kernel? That doesn't happen automatically (unfortunately).

Comment: I had no idea that 6.5 needed gcc-12, so that was my mistake. I did attempt to install it and reinstall but I had no luck. I changed to kernel 5.15, repurged my nvidia drivers again, and reinstalled nvidia-driver-525 with gcc-11 and no luck still. I actually made things worse though because nvidia-smi no longer works with this error. I'll update the original post with some of the info along with a new nvidia pkg search.

Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch

Comment: Well, Canonical's mistake actually ;^(  My hwe upgrade to 6.5 kernel worked fine since I already had a gcc-12 present from some other automatic install.  I cannot say if I could have dropped back to the 6.2 kernel (never tried it) and have purged the old 6.2 packages. I  do know with the 6.5 kernel present, a compile with a 5.15 kernel will produce the Nvidia.ko module using the gcc-12. (strings nvidia.ko |grep gcc will show which compiler was used.) With gcc-12 and a 6.5 kernel, an nvidia install should produce a 6.5 version of the module from any running kernel. Then reboot to the 6.5.

Comment: @ubfan1 You were right around gcc-12.I fixed that and am on 6.5 and 535 and removed all the other version. My display ports are still not working unfortunately. Do you have any other idea, recommendation, settings I can share that might help debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After everything of the version changes to work with 6.5 and 535 and gcc-12, I was able to get my display ports working again by unplugging everything, including the power for an extended period of time. After that I turned on my computer and then plugged the display port in, and then the power for the monitors. At that point it was able to work again.

Thank you for letting me know about gcc-12 with 6.5 and fresh install. I wouldn't have been able to get it working without that.

Comment: Looks like a fix was made today.  A fresh install using the Ubuntu 22.04.1 Desktop ISO now brings in the gcc-12 compiler automatically, so the Nvidia module gets build properly with the kernel update to 6.5.

Comment: Perfect timing :). Thanks again for mentioning gcc-12. I wouldn't have been able to get it fix without it.